# How to fix "ValueError: view limit minimum -36881.6 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value."?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

I have a data frame `daily_data_f_no_nr` containing following values:

```
          Day  Total TODO/TODOE count  First Derivative
0  2020-05-16                      35               0.0
1  2020-05-17                      35               0.0
2  2020-05-18                      35               0.0
3  2020-05-19                      35               0.0
4  2020-05-20                      35               0.0
..        ...                     ...               ...
67 2020-07-22                     151               0.0
68 2020-07-23                     151               0.0
69 2020-07-24                     152               1.0
70 2020-07-25                     152               0.0
71 2020-07-26                     152               0.0
```

When I call `fig = daily_data_f_no_nr.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26).get_figure()`  I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py\todo-count-delta.py", line 112, in <module>
    fig = daily_data_f_no_nr.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26).get_figure()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 847, in __call__
    return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py", line 61, in plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 269, in generate
    self._post_plot_logic_common(ax, self.data)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 438, in _post_plot_logic_common
    self._apply_axis_properties(ax.yaxis, fontsize=self.fontsize)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 520, in _apply_axis_properties
    labels = axis.get_majorticklabels() + axis.get_minorticklabels()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1252, in get_majorticklabels
    ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1407, in get_major_ticks
    numticks = len(self.get_majorticklocs())
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1324, in get_majorticklocs
    return self.major.locator()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 1428, in __call__
    self.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 1448, in refresh
    dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 1199, in viewlim_to_dt
    .format(vmin))
ValueError: view limit minimum -36881.6 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

How can I fix it?

**Update 1:** When I change the line in question to

```
fig = daily_data_f_no_nr.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26, xticks='Day', yticks='Total TODO/TODOE count').get_figure()
```

I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3732, in set_yticks
    ret = self.yaxis.set_ticks(ticks, minor=minor)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1755, in set_ticks
    self.set_view_interval(min(ticks), max(ticks))
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1892, in setter
    setter(self, min(vmin, vmax, oldmin), max(vmin, vmax, oldmax),
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

**Update 2:** This one works `fig = daily_data_f_no_nr.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26, xticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Day'], yticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Total TODO/TODOE count']).get_figure()`.

Comment: Are you sure `Day` column is converted to datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the y and xticks args from `.plot()` to  `Total TODO/TODOE count` and `Day`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html